# Make center point of rotation in center

Tags: javascript, css, animation, rotation

I am trying to rotate an element with animation. I was able to successfully implement that, but the problem is, when it rotates, the text in the `div` doesn't rotate from the middle, so it comes out that it's a bit wobbly.

How can I make the center point of the rotation in the middle of the `div`?

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/purL5mz9/1/)

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
  buttonContainer = document.getElementById('buttonContainer'),
  button = document.getElementById('button');

buttonContainer.addEventListener('click', expandElem);

function expandElem(e) {
  toggleClass(button, 'expand');
}

function hasClass(ele, cls) {
  return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(ele, cls) {
  if (!hasClass(ele, cls)) ele.className += " " + cls;
}

function removeClass(ele, cls) {
  if (hasClass(ele, cls)) {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)');
    ele.className = ele.className.replace(reg, function(match) {
      if (match.match(/^\s.+\s$/) !== null) return ' ';
      else return '';
    });
  }
}

function toggleClass(element, className) {
  if (!element || !className) return;

  if (hasClass(element, className)) removeClass(element, className);
  else addClass(element, className);
}
```

```css
#buttonContainer {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
}
#button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
#button.expand {
  transform: rotate(630deg);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
#container {
  margin: auto;
  top: 5vh;
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s 0.45s, height 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0.25s, max-width 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0.35s, width 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0.35s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <span id="button">&#128339;</span>
    <span id="title">History</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason is that the actual glyph of the clock isn't centered vertically...it's a font issue. The 'clock' is actually slightly biased towards the top - https://jsfiddle.net/w8qh4ehj/

Comment: @Paulie_D I think you hit it on the 'dot'! How can I know how many pixels it is off?

Comment: No idea, you'd have to play it a while and see what trial & error gets you. Couple of pixels of top padding might be about right.

Comment: @Paulie_D How do I know when it's exact?

Comment: When it looks right..I played with the line-height/width and this looks right on my screen as a fiddle but not in a Stack Snippet. - https://jsfiddle.net/w8qh4ehj/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line-height: 63.5px; gives you 4pixel top 4pixel bottom measured it with photoshop.

Comment: Thanks! I just measured it, the top is 18 and the bottom is 19